# TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

Any suggestions on this? I recently upgraded to "0.70.3"(React-Native) and encountered this error when running on IOS simulator  **TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined, js engine: hermes.**

package.json

```
{
  "name": "juzappnoexpo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "patch-package",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.8",
    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^4.0.4",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.12",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.1.7",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^7.0.0-alpha.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.6",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.6",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.3.0",
    "fbjs": "^3.0.0",
    "immer": "^9.0.1",
    "lodash.remove": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.3",
    "react-native-aes-crypto": "^1.3.10",
    "react-native-audio-recorder-player": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-camera": "git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.git",
    "react-native-contacts": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-draggable": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-event-source": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.7",
    "react-native-form-component": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.0",
    "react-native-image-filter-kit": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-incall-manager": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-keychain": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-logs": "^3.0.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-photo-editor": "^1.0.12",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.13",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-remix-icon": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-rsa-native": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-user-avatar": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-walkthrough-tooltip": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-webrtc": "^1.100.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-use-elmish": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "rn-checkbox-list": "^1.1.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "rn-sliding-up-panel": "^2.4.5",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "ts-assert-unreachable": "^0.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "@simbathesailor/use-what-changed": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.63.48",
    "@types/react-native-event-source": "^1.1.0",
    "@types/react-native-incall-manager": "^3.2.1",
    "@types/react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^0.5.3",
    "@types/react-native-push-notification": "^7.3.3",
    "@types/react-native-video": "^5.0.8",
    "@types/react-native-webrtc": "^1.75.4",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.0",
    "@welldone-software/why-did-you-render": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.16",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

One thing to remember to answer this question is that you have to disable hermes engine for a while to find the solution. Once you disable hermes, you get an error string like this: `_reactNative.Image.propTypes.source`.

It is this `source`  which is the property of undefined `propTypes`.

Now you have to enable search inside `node_modules` by going into your `settings.json` (USER) file and type this there.

> "search.exclude": {   "**/node_modules": false, },

Once you save this, in the VSCode global search of your project paste the error string you got in previous step.

> _reactNative.Image.propTypes.source

Most probably you will find this exact string inside `react-native-slider` package. It will be visible like this,

> thumbImage:_reactNative.Image.propTypes.source,

Now simply anywhere in the top declare:

> var _reactNativeImagePropType=require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types").ImagePropTypes;

And replace `_reactNative.Image.propTypes.source` with `_reactNativeImagePropType`

Comment: Making this change got the app building, but then caused this runtime crash:

Failed prop type: Slider: prop type `thumbImage` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `object`.This often happens because of typos such as `PropTypes.function` instead of `PropTypes.func`